# Laravel receiving Json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to receive JSON with Laravel like this:

Controller:

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd(Input::all());
    }
```

Also tried this:

```
dd(Request::json()->all());
```

But it's both not working. This is the test Json I send with postman:

```
{“parameters” : [{
        “email”:”test@test.com",
        “password”:”testtesttest”
    }]
}
```

Comment: `dd( $request->input('<parameter_name>') ) ;` should be enough

Comment: how are you sending this with postman? raw?

Comment: Yes sending raw. But @Moppo when I do for example dd( $request->input('<parameter_name>') ) ; it returns null.

Comment: so probably you are not receiving any parameter with the request. Are you sure the json data is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending your Json like this:

```
{"parameters": [{"email":"test@test.com","password":"testtest"}]}
```

It probably thinks it isn't formatted properly and discards it.

You may want the `Content-Type: application/json` header set as well.

Comment: Yes had to turn header to application/json. Now when I do: $test = $request->input('parameters'); and it returns everything how could I only receive "email". When I do $request->input('email'); that's not working?

Comment: @jamie $request->input('parameters')['email']

Comment: @naneri Thanks but that's not working it's telling me: Undefined index: email

Comment: I am not sure what version you are on but ... `$request->input('parameters.0.email')` or `$request->input('parameters.*.email')` to get all the possible emails in there.